# MasterPage and some Sites do not work after I attach content DB to new Web APP

Tags: master-page, web-application, content-database, database-attach

I have created a new web application `http://newtest/news` on new sharepoint server machine. After creating web app and deploying all the solution files that I grab from old sharepoint server machine, I notice that some of the sites and master page did not work and gives this error:

```
The Web application at http://test/news could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
```

I notice that it still shows old web application address `http://test/news` 
How can I change this old URL so that sites should work with new web application `http://newtest/news`

Comment: is there any hardcoded url in your page?

Comment: It seems like its hardcoded. Since its not developed by me.